# Jtable inserting in JTextpane using null layout

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

How to create jTable in JTextPane using null layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches. E.g. insert table http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html

You can add `JTable` as usual component using add() method and setting bounds to the `JTable`.

The third way is to call insertComponent() passing the `JTable`