# Printing a JPanel with Scrollable Jtable On it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I just want to print a `JPanel` which has a scrollable `JTable` on it.

I have oriented `JPanel` with `JTable` on it. But I can print only visible area.

The contents in scrollable `JTable` area are not printed.

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't.  You should consider using something like JasperReports

Comment: what if i want to use this method?

Comment: iam trying to avoid using api ,as far as i can

Comment: Then you're going to have no end of problems. Multi-page printing is pain in the back at the best of times, while `JTable` alone does this well, mixing other components into the picture is just asking for trouble

Comment: my problem is i want to generate a bill . with some logo,bill number,etc over the header,of bill and data on bellow it like a table ..

Comment: [This is the kind of idea of what I'm talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433).  Basically, you're going to have create a `JPanel` with the content you want on it, except that the `JScrollPane`'s preferredSize will have to match the `JTable`'s + the header's preferredSize and then follow something like the link above

Comment: *"can you suggest me a better way"* - I did, but you don't want to use it

Comment: If you put all your text and images in table cells, you could try the `JTable.print` method that is described in [The Java Tutorials - Printing Support in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html).

Comment: i tried it but.i want some extra information to be displayed over this table

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn I'm assuming that because the OP has the table in a `JScrollPane`, they have other components that they want to print, along with it, I could be completely crazy, but that's my take on the subject

Comment: You could also generate a pdf and print that.

Comment: @shubham Like what?  `JTable` supports header and footer

Comment: my problem is i want to generate a bill . with some logo,bill number,etc over the header,of bill and data on bellow it like a table ..

Comment: Again: consider using a pdf (or putting all your data in the table).

Comment: can you guide me with solving this problem using jasper report

Comment: I have another suggestion: put all your components (logo, number, table...) in a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` and print the contents of that text component. (See maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374794/jtable-inserting-in-jtextpane-using-null-layout)).

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn Generating a PDF would require a third party API which the op seems to want to avoid, otherwise they could use jasper reports and print to what ever they wanted :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are completely right! I was thinking of the nice [iText PDF library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/), which is of course a third party tool.

Comment: whixh one is best itext or jasper report?

Comment: i used itext it generates pdf.. but it would be helpfull if we could print directly without generating a file

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why I suggest using something like Jasper Reports, this has taken the better part of two days to nut out.  `JTable` doesn't like been treated this way.

Basically, there is the "UI view", which shows the data on the screen and the "print view" which used to generate the print out.

UI View...

[image: UI View]

Print view...

[image: Print View]

This example, on A4 paper, will generate 22 pages...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.DialogTypeSelection;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            int columnCount = 10;
            for (int index = 0; index < columnCount; index++) {
                model.addColumn((char) ('A' + index));
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row++) {
                Object[] data = new Object[columnCount];
                for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
                    data[col] = row + "x" + col;
                }
                model.addRow(data);
            }

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
            JButton print = new JButton("Print");
            add(print, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        PrintPane printPane = new PrintPane(model);

                        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                        aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
                        aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI));
                        aset.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);

                        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                        pj.setPrintable(printPane);

                        PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
                        pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

                        if (pj.printDialog(aset)) {
                            try {
                                pj.print(aset);
                            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class PrintPane extends JPanel implements Printable {

        private JTable table;

        public PrintPane(TableModel model) throws IOException {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            BufferedImage logo = ImageIO.read(...);
            JLabel header = new JLabel("Honest Bob's Used Ponys", new ImageIcon(logo), JLabel.LEFT);
            header.setFont(header.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
            header.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(header, gbc);

            table = new JTable(model);
            JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(tableHeader, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JTable(model), gbc);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        private int lastPage = 0;
        private double yOffset;

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            String name = "I be mighty!";
            String page = Integer.toString(pageIndex);

            double height = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
            double width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();

            System.out.println("Page = " + width + "x" + height);

            JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
            Dimension size = tableHeader.getPreferredSize();
            tableHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) width, size.height));
            tableHeader.setSize(table.getPreferredSize());

            size = table.getPreferredSize();
            table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) width, size.height));
            table.setSize(table.getPreferredSize());

            size = getPreferredSize();
            setSize((int)width, size.height);
            invalidate();
            doLayout();

            table.doLayout();
            tableHeader.doLayout();

            if (lastPage != pageIndex) {
                lastPage = pageIndex;
                yOffset = height * pageIndex;
                if (yOffset > getHeight()) {
                    yOffset = -1;
                }
            }

            if (yOffset >= 0) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();

                g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),
                        (int) pageFormat.getImageableY());

                g2d.translate(0, -yOffset);
                printAll(g2d);

                g2d.dispose();

                result = PAGE_EXISTS;
                System.out.println("Print page " + pageIndex);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

There is one significant problem, the fact that a row might be split over two pages.  This would require you to be able to calculate the number of rows which would fit onto the page and clip the `Graphics` accordingly, but I'll leave that to you to figure out

Comment: can you provide me a simple and good example on jasper report.i've looked on some of but its complex.it would be helpfull if you  could provide a example on  jasper report

Comment: @shubham Start by having a look at Jaspersoft Studio, which is a visual editor for Jasper Reports

Comment: Pink ponies? Really?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It helps my sanity

Comment: Well, OK, but it makes me sort of question it myself

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm a software developer, I don't have any :P

Answer (score 2):

*nb: This answer basically extends from the previous, but wouldn't have fitted into the other answer*

Example using Jasper Reports

JasperReports is an investment of time.  While the learning curve can be steep, once you start getting your head into it, it's very, very flexible.  We use to have to write no less then 3 exports for each report our project had to export (including the UI), now, we write one and it exports to PDF, printer, excel (and word, html).  When you want to change the report (ie, add page numbering), it's one place that gets changed and the code basically remains the same

- Generated with [JasperReports Library 6.2.0](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases)
- Using [JasperSoft Studio 6.2.0](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio/releases)

You'll also need

- [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) (I was using 1.1.2)
- [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) (I was using 3.2.1)
- [Apache Commons Digester](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/) (I was using 2/2.1)
- [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) (I was using (1.9.2)
- [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (I was using 2.7)

[image: Jasper Reports]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFilllListener;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.FillListener;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            int columnCount = 10;
            for (int index = 0; index < columnCount; index++) {
                model.addColumn((char) ('A' + index));
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row++) {
                Object[] data = new Object[columnCount];
                for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
                    data[col] = row + "x" + col;
                }
                model.addRow(data);
            }

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
            JButton print = new JButton("Print");
            add(print, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    List<ReportData> data = new ArrayList<>(model.getRowCount());
                    for (int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); row++) {
                        ReportData reportData = new ReportData();
                        for (int col = 0; col < model.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                            reportData.add((String) model.getValueAt(row, col));
                        }
                        data.add(reportData);
                    }

                    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this), "Generating Report");
                    dialog.setModal(true);
                    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                    dialog.setContentPane(panel);
                    dialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait..."));
                    dialog.pack();

                    PrintWorker printWorker = new PrintWorker(data);
                    printWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                            PrintWorker worker = (PrintWorker) evt.getSource();
                            String name = evt.getPropertyName();
                            if ("state".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                if (worker.isDone()) {
                                    dialog.setVisible(false);

                                    try {
                                        worker.get();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if ("status".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                ReportStatus status = worker.getStatus();
                                switch (status) {
                                    case FAILED:
                                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Report Generation Failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        break;
                                    case CANCELLED:
                                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Report Generation was Cancelled", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                                        break;
                                    case COMPLETED:
                                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                                        System.out.println("Yippe :)");
                                        JasperPrint jp = worker.getJasperPrint();
                                        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                                        aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI));
                                        aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);

                                        JRPrintServiceExporter printer = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
                                        printer.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jp));

                                        SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
                                        configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(aset);
                                        configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
                                        configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(true);
                                        printer.setConfiguration(configuration);

                                        try {
                                            printer.exportReport();
                                        } catch (JRException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    printWorker.execute();

                    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(TestPane.this);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class ReportData {
        private List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public List<String> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void add(String value) {
            data.add(value);
        }

    }

    public enum ReportStatus {
        FAILED, COMPLETED, CANCELLED;
    }

    public static class PrintWorker extends SwingWorker<ReportStatus, Void> {

        private List<ReportData> data;
        private ReportStatus status = ReportStatus.FAILED;
        private JasperPrint jasperPrint;

        private ReentrantLock waitLock = new ReentrantLock();
        private Condition waitCon = waitLock.newCondition();

        public PrintWorker(List<ReportData> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public ReportStatus getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public JasperPrint getJasperPrint() {
            return jasperPrint;
        }

        @Override
        protected ReportStatus doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test/reports/SalesReport.jasper")) {

                JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);

                Map<String, Object> mapParameters = new HashMap<>(5);
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/test/images/Logo.png"));
                mapParameters.put("LOGO", img);

                AsynchronousFillHandle handler = AsynchronousFillHandle.createHandle(report, mapParameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data));
                handler.addFillListener(new FillListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void pageGenerated(JasperPrint jp, int i) {
                        System.out.println("Page Generated " + i);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void pageUpdated(JasperPrint jp, int i) {
                        System.out.println("Page Update " + i);
                    }

                });
                handler.addListener(new AsynchronousFilllListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void reportFinished(final JasperPrint jp) {
                        System.out.println("Finished...");
                        status = ReportStatus.COMPLETED;
                        jasperPrint = jp;
                        firePropertyChange("status", null, status);
                        waitLock.lock();
                        try {
                            waitCon.signalAll();
                        } finally {
                            waitLock.unlock();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void reportCancelled() {
                        System.out.println("Cancelled...");
                        status = ReportStatus.CANCELLED;
                        firePropertyChange("status", null, status);
                        waitLock.lock();
                        try {
                            waitCon.signalAll();
                        } finally {
                            waitLock.unlock();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void reportFillError(Throwable thrwbl) {
                        System.out.println("Failed...");
                        status = ReportStatus.FAILED;
                        firePropertyChange("status", null, status);

                        thrwbl.printStackTrace();

                        waitLock.lock();
                        try {
                            waitCon.signalAll();
                        } finally {
                            waitLock.unlock();
                        }
                    }
                });
                handler.startFill();

            }

            waitLock.lock();
            try {
                waitCon.await();
            } finally {
                waitLock.unlock();
            }

            System.out.println("All done here");
            return status;
        }

    }
}
```

## JasperReport jxml

Now, in the 3-4 years I've been using JasperReports, I've never written the jxml manually, I've always used the form editor, but, just so you can paste this in...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2015-12-08T11:39:14 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SalesReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3d6825b2-df5d-47ee-a901-26f4c5fa3429">
    <parameter name="LOGO" class="java.awt.Image" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="data" class="java.util.List"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="107" splitType="Stretch">
            <image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" uuid="3d8b698a-aaa1-45d4-b979-2c2f70ab3858">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="cm"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{LOGO}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="105" y="0" width="450" height="100" uuid="eb5d50a7-5931-4473-b2e5-56766c4263d6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="36" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Honest Bob's Used Ponies]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="36" uuid="e30efc2e-843d-4c1e-b28a-760ac3166e75">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="761a067d-03b3-4e91-92af-08e1ea4d03dd">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[B]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="1b753893-a380-4a77-8938-3dcea6486383">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[C]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="c46b1125-8c9c-4768-9267-75c87bf2c7c3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[D]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="225" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="dfe91e74-f722-43cf-9a34-a4cd0ca202a1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[E]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="e5504504-c5a5-4c36-a3a0-3702cc52609c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[F]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="335" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="c9e49d80-fc80-4f64-ae43-9ac4da4a3fda">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[G]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="9ad6dcae-605d-47e8-bdee-e230dea5970c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[H]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="445" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="9ed989a1-d8fa-45d4-812b-42ed4de292b0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[I]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="55" height="36" uuid="ba50fbea-9323-4c5d-814c-356d1752ecd6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[J]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="16" uuid="d3d12d31-bce2-4850-8c68-4ca336869302"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(0)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="c30464ca-c723-4378-abf0-0c1e9d282a14"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(1)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="7451163c-37da-48fa-aa42-b62e7e81bb3c"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(2)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="4038f5d0-bfc5-475c-91cd-103e0dee7cf9"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(3)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="225" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="f7369acd-ad91-4170-ac4f-b46a888666e1"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(4)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="942c7d77-39c0-4632-8c73-c18d6a27ed66"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(5)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="335" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="dcea008b-b4c4-480c-8853-ef60eca945c6"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(6)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="17e05f28-ae3c-4ecf-baff-77ff2d2aab66"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(7)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="445" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="4dad91f1-0451-403b-a02c-6eb26d58ea97"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(8)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="55" height="16" uuid="0b584a93-a736-4fa3-b7b9-dcb909638aad"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data}.get(9)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="16" backcolor="rgba(0, 84, 73, 0.1254902)" uuid="8ba2fd94-84a3-4b28-86c2-7c4306b64774">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean( $V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 != 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="16">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="235" y="0" width="275" height="16" uuid="db59b963-ace0-4103-a6e2-81ec2d02c6bb"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="510" y="0" width="45" height="16" uuid="13f222e8-e2fd-437e-a9ca-95c1d0c8736f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: If answering a question requires *this much code and exposition*, then perhaps the question is too broad?

Comment: I answered the question the way that the op wanted, but also wanted a jasper reports example - the vide itself is short, but the jxml is what would have pushed me over the character limit. It's not that e question was (originally) to broad, it's the fact that any solution is complex and involved