# Is jTable suitable for printing reports in java desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, report

I want to print a table with formal format like logo with leading company multi line header and report header is that applicable with JTable?
if not please provide me with the best alternative.

Comment: Yes and no. You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959) example which adds a icon to the first page to see some of the complex issues involved if you want to customise the way that the printing works. Personally, I prefer to use Jasper Reports, apart from been built to do this kind of work and having lots of possible export options, it's also much eaiser to customise

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, please guide me what i want to run jasper reports on client pc and explain if i want anything plus jre.

Comment: Start with [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/download) - you'll want the library and studio

Comment: I meant when i deploy desktop application with jasper reports on client side is i need to install anything in client side plus JRE

Comment: No. You only need the JRE and the jasper reports libraries

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have previously used Apache FOP (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) and jasper Reports(http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).
both of them use XMl templates and you could Fill Data and extract various report formats (i.e. RTF, PDF, html).

Answer (score 0):

`JTable` offers printing capabilities including header and footer through its `print()`methods. Both are based upon `MessageFormat`, though. So while you will get multi line headers and footers, you won`t get a company logo inside there.

Comment: *"you won`t get a company logo inside there."* - Unless your mad a do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959)