# Print Jasper Reports in JAVA

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

i am using a report in iReports, but I would want to print this with something changes in configuration for example: Copies, Orientation, Sides and others things; but it is not possible for me.

The fragment code is that:

```
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:/ds");
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        String report = JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("report.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>(), connection);
        String defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName().toLowerCase();
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        PrintService selectedService = null;

        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(Sides.DUPLEX);

        for (PrintService service : services) {
            String existingPrinter = service.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (existingPrinter.equals(defaultPrinter)) {
                selectedService = service;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (selectedService != null) {
            printerJob.setPrintService(selectedService);

            boolean printSucceed = JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
        }
```

I am using java language, help me please.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [second example in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it), it provides some simple exampls of providing printer attrbutes to the `JRPrintServiceExporter`

Comment: Is it possible in a Java Web application?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, as you don't have access to the user's printer, the best you can do is provide PDF - but I'm not a web guy