# Java - Print titles with different font in the same page

Tags: java, swing, printing

I want to print 2 titles with different font, and then print a table's header and all rows with another font. I have the table content in a `JTable`. When the user clicks a button, I want to send all the things to the `PrinterServices` and print them with `LANDSCAPE` orientation. There may be many rows so I need to do the pagination. The pagination is in the left bottom.

I see there's no possibility to use `JTable.print` because I need the title in `font1`, the subtitle in `font2`, and the table header/table data in `font3`.

How can I do that?

I have seen this page, shows me how to print with different style in several pages:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PrintinJavapageformatanddocument.htm

But I think this link place the different styles in different pages, and in my situation, the `title1` and `title2` are in the first page, and the rest of the page is filled with row data, and then page 2, page 3... So it contains several styles in the same page and is not exactly what the link does.

EDIT:

Now I have these code, but they are not working in two aspects:

1. I must set the orientation in the print dialog prompt (choose the "Horizontal" orientation). I want it by default, but I don't want the Java native page setup dialog. I want the system dependant one.
2. The left margin/indent increases as the page number increases. I want it static. I must have messed up the coordinates.
3. The pagination foot is not there. How can I get it?

So I have:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;

public class PrintingTest1 {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        //cross-platform print dialog, java l&f
//        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        //java page setup dialog
//        PageFormat pf = job.getPageFormat(aset);
//        job.setPrintable(new PrintingTest1().new HelloWorldPrinter(), pf);
        //java print setup dialog
//        boolean doPrint = job.printDialog(aset);
//        if (doPrint) {
//            try {
//                job.print(aset);
//            } catch (PrinterException e) {
//                System.out.println("Cancelled. ");
//            }
//        }

        //native print dialog

        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        Font font1 = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        Font font2 = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        Font font3 = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 9);
        HelloWorldPrinter printer = new PrintingTest1().new HelloWorldPrinter();
        printer.setFont1(font1);
        printer.setFont2(font2);
        printer.setFont3(font3);

        printer.setTitle1("Title 1: Main title");
        printer.setTitle2line1("Title 2 line 1: top");
        printer.setTitle2line2("Title 2 line 2: bot");
        printer.setHeaderline1("HeaderLine1: top");
        printer.setHeaderline2("HeaderLine2: bot");

        String[][] rows = new String[85][2];
        for (int i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = new String[] {"row " + i + ", line 1", "      row " + i + ", line 2"};
        }
        printer.setRows(rows.length);

        printer.setRowsData(rows);
        job.setPrintable(printer);
        boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                System.out.println("Cancelled. ");
            }
        }
    }


    class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable {
        private Font font1;
        private Font font2;
        private Font font3;

        private int lineHeight1;
        private int lineHeight2;
        private int lineHeight3;

        private String title1;
        private String title2line1;
        private String title2line2;
        private String headerline1;
        private String headerline2;

        private String[][] rowsData;

        /** 
         * Number of rows in the table
         */
        private int rows;

        /**
         * Number of lines of data to print. 2*rows.
         */
        private int dataLines;

        private int pageLimit;
        private int linesDataOnPage0;
        private int linesOnPage0;
        private int linesPerPage;

        /**
         * The array index of row data when every new pages starts to print.
         */
        private int newStartIndex;
        public void setRows(int rows) {
            this.rows = rows;
        }

        public void setFont1(Font font1) {
            this.font1 = font1;
        }

        public void setFont2(Font font2) {
            this.font2 = font2;
        }

        public void setFont3(Font font3) {
            this.font3 = font3;
        }


        public void setTitle1(String title1) {
            this.title1 = title1;
        }

        public void setTitle2line1(String title2line1) {
            this.title2line1 = title2line1;
        }

        public void setTitle2line2(String title2line2) {
            this.title2line2 = title2line2;
        }

        public void setHeaderline1(String headerline1) {
            this.headerline1 = headerline1;
        }

        public void setHeaderline2(String headerline2) {
            this.headerline2 = headerline2;
        }

        public void setRowsData(String[][] rowsData) {
            this.rowsData = rowsData;
        }

        public HelloWorldPrinter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        private int calculatePageLimit(int dataLines, Graphics g, PageFormat pf) {
            FontMetrics metrics1 = g.getFontMetrics(font1);
            FontMetrics metrics2 = g.getFontMetrics(font2);
            FontMetrics metrics3 = g.getFontMetrics(font3);
            lineHeight1 = metrics1.getHeight();
            lineHeight2 = metrics2.getHeight();
            lineHeight3 = metrics3.getHeight();

            double pageHeight = pf.getImageableHeight();

            //title 1, title 2 (2 lines), header (2 lines)
            linesDataOnPage0 = (int)((pageHeight - lineHeight1 - lineHeight2*2 - lineHeight3*2) / lineHeight3);
            linesOnPage0 = linesDataOnPage0 + 5;

            linesPerPage = (int)pageHeight / lineHeight3;

            int pageLimit0 = 0;
            if (dataLines <= linesDataOnPage0) {
                pageLimit0 = 1; //all data can be printed on the first page.
            } else {
                int lastPageLines = (dataLines - linesDataOnPage0) % linesPerPage;
                pageLimit0 = (dataLines - linesDataOnPage0 - lastPageLines) / linesPerPage + 2;
            }

            return pageLimit0;
        }
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            if (pageLimit == 0) { //not calculated yet.
                this.dataLines = rows * 2;
                pageLimit = calculatePageLimit(dataLines, graphics, pageFormat);
            }
            Paper papel = new Paper();
            papel.setImageableArea(72, 72, 697, 450);
            papel.setSize(841, 595);
            pageFormat.setPaper(papel);
            pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

            if (pageIndex < pageLimit) {
                int y = 10;

                if (pageIndex == 0) {
                    // 1. print the title 1
                    g2d.setFont(font1);
                    g2d.drawString(title1, 10, y);
                    y += lineHeight1;

                    // 2. print title 2
                    g2d.setFont(font2);
                    g2d.drawString(title2line1, 10, y);
                    y += lineHeight2;
                    g2d.drawString(title2line2, 10, y);
                    y += lineHeight2;

                    // 3. print header
                    g2d.setFont(font3);
                    g2d.drawString(headerline1, 10, y);
                    y += lineHeight3;
                    g2d.drawString(headerline2, 10, y);
                    y += lineHeight3;

                    // 4. print data
                    for (int i=0; i< (int)(linesDataOnPage0 / 2); i++) {
                        g2d.drawString(rowsData[i][0], 10, y);
                        y += lineHeight3;
                        g2d.drawString(rowsData[i][1], 10, y);
                        y += lineHeight3;
                    }

                    y = 0;
                    newStartIndex = (int)(linesDataOnPage0 / 2);
                    return PAGE_EXISTS;
                } else {
                    int end;
                    if (newStartIndex + (int)(linesPerPage / 2)  > rowsData.length) {
                        end = rowsData.length;
                    } else {
                        end = newStartIndex + (int)(linesPerPage / 2);
                    }
                    g2d.setFont(font3);
                    for (int i=newStartIndex; i< end; i++) {
                        g2d.drawString(rowsData[i][0], 10, y);
                        y += lineHeight3;
                        g2d.drawString(rowsData[i][1], 10, y);
                        y += lineHeight3;
                    }

                    y = 0;
                    newStartIndex +=(int)(linesPerPage / 2);
                    return PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
            } else {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe post some code and show an example of what you mean. its hard to understand without visualization

Comment: In a case like this, I'd recommend something like Jasper Reports, demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question to show more code. And, if anyone want to close the question, please, **leave a comment to explain yourself beforehand. Show some respect, if you wouldn't mind**.