# How to print jTextfield with some values

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm try to print some data in this order:

1. Herder
2. Date(Jtextfield)
3. Invoice no(Jtextfield)
4. Jtable
5. Amount (Jtextfield)
6. Footer

   ```
    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Building Materials Coperation Ltd");
    MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Thank you! Come again..");
    MessageFormat Date = new MessageFormat("Date " + txt_date.getText());
    MessageFormat Inoice_no = new MessageFormat("Invoice No " + txt_invoice_no.getText());
    MessageFormat Amount = new MessageFormat("Total Amount:- Rs" + txt_Total_amount.getText());


    try {
    PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    jTable2.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, Date, false, set, false);
    jTable2.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, Inoice_no, Amount, false, set, false);
    jTable2.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, Inoice_no, footer, false, set, false);

    } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + "Error from Printer Job "
         + "\n" + e);   
    }
   ```

So i have got print but,it gets 3 pop ups window to print it
How can i print in order

I hope,you will help me to find that
 (Can you give me and examples,Its big help)
Thanks

Comment: You have two basic options, you can create your own custom `Printable` to do what you want, see [Printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html) for more details, have fun with sorting out the paging issues OR you can use something like Jasper Reports, which would probably be a lot simpler

Comment: Each time you call `print`, it's a new print job, which is likely the cause of you getting three popups

Comment: give me an examples please

Comment: [That's probably the best example I think of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959) - otherwise, I recommend reading the link I posted earlier and doing some research into printing

Comment: Printing is very complex, what you're asking is even more complex, printing a `JTable` in a mixed output like you're asking means that you can't rely on the table's inbuilt printing support, but instead, have to do the work yourself - which is why, you won't get fully runnable example which meets your needs and why I recommend Jasper Reports instead

Comment: Please tell How to install iReport on my windows 8 pc without any errors