# How to print a invoice with image in heder with jtable and jtextfield with fotter

Tags: java, printing

I want to print a invoice, like this

[image]

So I used this codes to do that.

```
// Testing for printing    

     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     MessageFormat[] header = new MessageFormat[3];
     header[0] = new MessageFormat("BUILDING MATERIALS COPERATION LTD");
     header[1] = new MessageFormat("");
     header[2] = new MessageFormat("Date - " + txt_date.getText() + "                  " 
                            + "Invoice No - " + txt_invoice_no.getText());

     MessageFormat[] footer = new MessageFormat[2];
     footer[0] = new MessageFormat("");
     footer[1] = new MessageFormat("Thank you! Come again..");

      try {
     PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

      job.setPrintable(new jTable(JTable2, PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer));

     } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + "Error from Printer Job "
          + "\n" + e); 

     // For printing a image like heder


     private static class Image implements Printable {…}
     private static class Title implements Printable {…}

     PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     Book book = new Book();
     ook.append(new Image(), pj.defaultPage());
     book.append(new Title(), pj.defaultPage());
     book.append(table.getPrintable(...), pj.defaultPage());
     book.append(new EndPage(), pj.defaultPage());
     pj.setPageable(book); 
     pj.print();
```

I want to handle that in one time,

but it has an error... 
How can I fix this problem and print a invoice like previously?

Comment: Could you post your error?

Comment: Start by having a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959) to understand the share level of complexity of your problem, then, have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067) to understand how it could be achieved using JasperReports instead