# Print JTable with logo at top of pdf file in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am building a java application which have Jtable and logo at the top of form I want to print the JTable and logo at the top of printed PDF File.
I found a way to put logo and JTable at JPanel and print it but when I did it Table didn't scrollable some of its data appeared but not all data
This is my Code which I use to print JTable

```
MessageFormat head = new MessageFormat("header");
MessageFormat foot = new MessageFormat("page {0}");

try {
   table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, head, foot);

} catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

How Can I do That ?
**Note**
I stored Logo in JLabel

Comment: Printing a `JTable` will show what's visible, as you discovered.  You'll have to [create a PDF table](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-table-in-a-pdf-using-java/) and print one line of the table at a time using your logical data model and whatever PDF commands you need to create a PDF table.  You have to handle what happens when your PDF table is longer than a printed page.

Comment: [This examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067) demonstrates two ways to place a logo at the top of a printable `JTable`.  I recommend trying the JasperReports one, as it will allow you to generate a PDF with little more effort