# How to compile jasper report only once and reuse while having dynamic inputs for 100k pdf creation

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, jasper-reports

I am having multiple jasper reports in D Drive, Now I am compiling jasper reports by taking values from request. It increasing processing time. Now its taking 5 min for creating 30 pdf files I want to minimize it to the 2-3 second, How I can achieve it?

```
package com.intellect.custodyedge;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFileVirtualizer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleWriterExporterOutput;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class GenController {

    private static final ExecutorService executorService;
    private static final String commonPath = "D:\\Jasper\\CustodyEdgeReports\\CustodyEdgeReports\\";
    private static final HikariDataSource dataSource;
    private static JasperReport jasperReport;
    static {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.26.18:1521:SIR19774");
        config.setUsername("ICUSTADM");
        config.setPassword("ICUSTADM");
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
//      try {
////            String reportFileName = commonPath + "reportTemplate.jrxml";
////            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportFileName);
//      } catch (JRException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//          throw new RuntimeException("Failed to compile the report template.");
//      }
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    }

    @PostMapping("/generate")
    public ResponseEntity generateReports(@RequestBody String requestBody) throws JRException, InterruptedException {

        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(requestBody);

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/GN_CommonReports.properties")) {
                properties.load(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read properties from the GN_CommonReports.properties file.");
            }

            String menuID = json.getString("menuID");

            String reportIdfromPro_file = menuID + ".REPORTID";
            String reportId = properties.getProperty(reportIdfromPro_file);

            String reportTitlefromPro_file = menuID + ".REPORTTITLE";
            String reportTitle = properties.getProperty(reportTitlefromPro_file);
            String reportFileName = commonPath + reportTitle + ".jrxml";
            String format = json.getString("FORMAT");
            String compressFlag = json.getString("COMPRESSFLAG");

            // Compile the Jasper report
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportFileName);
            String reportFieldfromPro_file = menuID + ".REPORTFIELDS";
            String reportfield = properties.getProperty(reportFieldfromPro_file);
            List<String> fieldNames = Arrays.asList(reportfield.split(","));

            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.size(); i++) {
                parameters.put(fieldNames.get(i), json.get(fieldNames.get(i)));
            }

            // Fill the report with data
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, con);

            // Generate the reports in parallel using ExecutorService
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
            List<String> formats = Arrays.asList("PDF", "CSV", "XML");
            formats.forEach(f -> {
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    try {
                        if ("PDF".equalsIgnoreCase(format) && "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(compressFlag)) {

                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
                            String outputFileName = reportTitle + timeStamp + ".pdf";
                            JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(100, "D:\\jasper\\JasperFrameworkPdf\\" + outputFileName);
                            virtualizer.setReadOnly(false);
                            jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.virtualizer", virtualizer.toString());

                            // Export the report to compressed PDF
                            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("D:\\jasper\\JasperFrameworkPdf\\" + outputFileName));
                            exporter.exportReport();
                            virtualizer.cleanup();

                        } else if ("CSV".equalsIgnoreCase(format) && "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(compressFlag)) {
                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
                            String outputFileName = reportTitle + timeStamp + ".pdf";
                            JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(10, "D:\\jasper\\JasperFrameworkPdf\\");
                            virtualizer.setReadOnly(false);
                            jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.virtualizer", virtualizer.toString());

                            // Export the report to CSV
                            JRCsvExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
                            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(
                                    "D:\\jasper\\JasperFrameworkPdf\\" + outputFileName));
                            exporter.exportReport();
                            virtualizer.cleanup();

                        } else {
                            System.err.println("Unsupported format: " + format);
                        }
                    } catch (JRException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            });
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

            System.out.println("DONE");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error generating reports");
        }
    }
}
```

Still not having any effect on performance and not able to achieve that finishing time.

Comment: I use to do this all the time, we had a build step which would compile the reports as part build process and the load the compll I’ll ed reports at runtime - [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067) demonstrates the runtime loading - you’ll have dig for it